# Adding screen share feature on a web application

Tags: screensharing

I am searching for an option to enable a screen sharing feature on my customer support application so that on a click of a button or a URL only, the client can share their screen without any external installation or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing screen contents as a live `MediaStream` is initiated by calling `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()`, which returns a promise that resolves to a stream containing the live screen contents.

[Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture) from mozilla.org